# C++ Why are the changes to my class attributes in my class methods not saving?

Tags: c++, object

I have a class that has `x`, `y`, and `mass` (which acts as radius) attributes. All of which are floats. I also have this method:

```cpp
float shrink(float attackerMass) {
    float shrinkAmount = attackerMass * GetFrameTime();
    mass -= shrinkAmount;

    return shrinkAmount;
}
```

This method is called when another circle is touching the circle, and it shrinks the circle by the right amount (I put an `std::cout` line underneath `mass -= shrinkAmount` to test it) but the value of mass is never actually applied to the object. My guess is that I'm somehow changing the value of a copy of my circle object and not the actual referenced one but I have no idea how that'd be happening.

Here's the entire object class if needed (I am using functions from Raylib):

```cpp
class Blib {
private:
    Color color;
    Blib* address{ this };
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float mass;
    
    /* Constructor */
    Blib(float x, float y, float mass = 32.0f, Color color = Color{ 255, 255, 255, 200 }) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->mass = mass;
        this->color = color;
    }

    /* Methods */
    void check_collisions(std::vector<Blib> blibs) { //

        for (Blib blib : blibs) {
            
            if (CheckCollisionCircles(Vector2{ x, y }, mass, Vector2{ blib.x, blib.y }, blib.mass)) {

                if (mass > blib.mass && address != blib.address) {
                    grow(blib.shrink(mass));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void draw() {
        DrawCircle(x, y, mass, color);
    }

    void grow(float amount) {
        mass += amount;
    }

    void move_with_keyboard() {
        float speed = 5.0f * mass * GetFrameTime();

        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_W)) {
            y -= speed;
        }

        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_A)) {
            x -= speed;
        }

        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_S)) {
            y += speed;
        }

        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_D)) {
            x += speed;
        }
    }

    float shrink(float attackerMass) {
        float shrinkAmount = attackerMass * GetFrameTime();
        mass -= shrinkAmount;

        return shrinkAmount;
    }
};
```

Comment: You probably want to get a reference to the object from the vector, this way I think there is a copy made in the loop

Comment: You're probably right, I'll let you know if this ends up being the problem.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yep, it was just a lack of referencing in my `check_collisions` method. Thanks!

Comment: It might be useful to mark the class as non-copyable (by deleting the copy constructor etc) if you don’t want copies made and then these kinds of problems would be eliminated. It may also cause other issues though, so shouldn’t be done without planning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
for (Blib blib : blibs)
```

Simply change to:

```
for (Blib &blib : blibs)
```

You want a reference, otherwise you are just changing a temporary variable that disappears at the end of each for loop iteration.

PS: I usually prefer:

```
for (auto &blib : blibs)
```

PPS: Your function signature also needs to be a reference:

```
void check_collisions(std::vector<Blib> &blibs)
```